# Black Screen After Nvidia Driver 331.79 install

Tags: graphics

All the other answers do not help, so I decided to do this. I have a GeForce 780 Ti and whenever I install Graphics Drivers I restart and boots up, and then it says Loading failsafe graphics driver [fail] and I do not even get to see the login screen. It just goes black screen with a orange underscore flashing, also Ctrl+Alt+F1-F7 does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing; that is the driver provided on the nVidia site.

I have had better luck with http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers  as described here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/479504/ubuntu-14-04-crashes-after-installing-nvidia-331-or-nvidia-current-driver-gtx-7/480551#480551

As you have nothing displayed I'd guess the active driver (which it might be) sets things wrong. Try running an `sudo sh N....run --uninstall` on the driver, followed by a cleanup and reinstall from the boot menu (safe boot... - I wish I'd remember the words) - using the information behind the link above.